# SuperMicro MBD-X8SIL-F-B, Intel Xeon X3430 and Crucial DDR3-1333 ECC RDIMM?

Tags: xeon, supermicro

I am assembling a custom PC. And here are the components I ordered:

Motherboard: SuperMicro MBD-X8SIL-F-B - http://www.supermicro.com/xeon_3400/Motherboard/X8SIL.cfm

Processor: Intel Xeon X3430

RAM: Crucial DDR3-1333 ECC RDIMM - http://www.crucial.com/store/partspecs.aspx?IMODULE=CT102472BB1339

When I power on the system, the yellow led on the motherboard (marked as no. 43 on the manual) is blinking, and I hear a continuos long beep. According to the manual, this happens when the memory installed is unsupported.

Am I installing the wrong memory? If yes, what alternatives do I have. I want to keep this motherboard. I can switch the Processor or the RAM. But I do need at least 24 GBs of RAM.

Thanks in advance.

Update: 
[http://www.amazon.com/Kingston-ValueRAM-1333MHz-Voltage-Desktop/dp/B004Z9Y2G0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325298911&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Z9Y2G0) worked like a charm :)

Comment: How many memory modules? Are they all the same? Which slots are they in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice on the Crucial page that the memory is dual-rank DDR3 RDIMM. Then click on the link under memory capacity on the SuperMicro page. If you look in Table 2, the table for DDR3 ECC RDIMM support, under dual rank, it says "Up to 16GB". So you can't support 24GB with dual-rank RDIMMs.

If you need to support 24GB, your only option is quad-ranked, DDR3 ECC RDIMMs. Unfortunately, I've never heard of such a part in any density above 4GB (which would max you out at 16GB again). So I don't know how you could get to 24GB. Perhaps someone else does.

Comment: David, thanks for the response. Yea it makes sense now. Do you think these (http://www.crucial.com/store/partspecs.aspx?IMODULE=CT102472BB1067Q) will work?

Comment: or these: http://www.amazon.com/Kingston-ValueRAM-1333MHz-Voltage-Desktop/dp/B004Z9Y2G0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325298911&sr=8-1

Comment: Oh, wow, they *do* exist. I believe those will work, but I am not 100% sure. I know of no reason why they wouldn't.